# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function - Google Maps setup. Extracted infowindow code due to hardcoded info

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-hooks

I researched my problem to possibly using the wrong version of Hooks React. So updated the version with: npm install --save react@^16.8.0 react-dom@^16.8.0. However, I continue to receive the same error in which I'm requesting assistance with.

Here is copy of code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import * as mapData from "../Map/map.js"
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components';

import { 
withScriptjs, 
withGoogleMap, 
GoogleMap, 
Marker,
InfoWindow
} from "react-google-maps";



function Map() {
  const [selectedPerson, setSelectedPerson] = useState(null);
  
    return(
      
     <GoogleMap 
       defaultZoom={13}
       defaultCenter={{ 
         lat: 20.516960, 
         lng: -100.800262 }} 
      > 
      {mapData.markers.map((person) => (
        <Marker
          key={person.individual.person_id}
          position={{
            lat: person.geometry.coordinates[0],
            lng: person.geometry.coordinates[1]
          }}
      
      onClick={() => {
        setSelectedPerson(person);
      }}
      />
      ))}

       {selectedPerson && (
         
      
      )} 
    </GoogleMap>
  );
  }

const WrappedMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Map))

export default function MapInit() {
  
   return (
     <div style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}
     
     >
     
       <WrappedMap 
       googleMapURL={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places&key=${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_KEY}`} 
       
       loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
       containerElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
       mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
       />
     </div>
   ); 
}
```

Error Line code:

98 |   );
99 |   }
100 |

> 101 | const WrappedMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Map))
> 102 |
> 103 | export default function MapInit() {
> 104 |
> I'm somewhat new to react/javascript and was able as mentioned above to upgrade the Hooks version to 16.8 by installing:  npm install --save react@^16.8.0 react-dom@^16.8.0

Comment: Which line are you getting the error on?

Comment: Can you also provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) of your code that shows the error? You can use [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/).